# Extracting one portion of 3D array

Tags: java, arrays

Apologies for what is probably a simple question but I am just a beginner and trying to learn what I can of Java.

I currently have a 3D array (array[][][]). What I want to do is loop through the array and save the third value to a variable.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                    (array[x][y][value]);
                    
                    int savedValue = value;
```

I guess I have something very small wrong but would be very grateful if somebody could help me out.

Comment: What do you expect `(array[x][y][value]);` to do?

Comment: which element of the of the 3rd dimension are you wanting to save?  You're currently only looping through the first 2 dimensions.  You also need to move your variable outside the loop or it will get redefined.  Also, your saving of the value would look more like `savedValue = array[x][y][z];`

Comment: @Ryan So the third dimension is only going to be a value of 5 or 10 and is why I'm not looping through it. So I'm trying to pull out for each x and y value whether the third dimension is 5 or 10. I can do some manipulation on that value then.

Comment: @Andy465 that still doesn't make any sense. You still have to index the array to get the value out regardless of what that value is.  You need 3 loops, 1 for x, 1 for y, and 1 for z, then you can pull out that value and do something with it.

Comment: @Ryan ok thanks for that I will add the third for loop for z. I am still stuck on how to pull the value out however. I run through my 3 for loops but how do I extract x and place it into a variable?